# Window switcher does not include dialogs

Tags: unity, 16.04, application-switcher, dialog

I noticed that the Unity 7 window switcher does not include some windows, more specifically dialogs like the Nautilus file transfer window. Is this intended behavior?

I found out a piece of software I use (Java-application using JDialogs) uses dialogs all the time, which annoyingly disappear behind other windows. As one can imagine having to minimize almost all other windows all the time to get back to those windows is annoying, as I cannot Alt-Tab to them.

I am using 16.04 right now, but this has been an annoyance for about three years right now, so it may have already been present since the new application-switcher was introduced.